# Mercurial Repository Architecture for Code Reviews

Tags: mercurial

We are in the process of moving to Mercurial from Clearcase (for version control) and to Jira/Crucible from ClearQuest (for issue tracking and code reviews). We perform mandatory pre-push reviews.

We have encountered a problem with Crucible and pre-push support, and we are looking for several solutions. The main way to resolve the problem is to make Atlassian products "watch" as least amount of repositories as possible (the issue we encountered is slowness that is directly linked to the amount of repositories watched).

What we do now is watch every single development repository to allow us to perform code reviews on them. We also have one central repository that holds a stable version. My question is how to plan our repository architecture so we can perform code reviews and still keep a clean central repository (I guess some sort of review repository is needed, but I can't figure out how to get it to work for several reviews at once).

Answer (score 0):

We do pre-push reviews the easy way: we use patches instead of having development repositories on a central server.

Only if we need to build something big, we create a development/feature repository on the server, but even then, we still review patches before pushing to those repos.

To enforce this, you need assign roles for pushing to the repos, instead of allowing all development team to push.